Understanding Functional Login Flow in ASP.NET Core Minimal APIs
I'm building an API with Minimal APIs as one does and I'm trying to understand how the login authentication/authorization works on a more practical level. I've a basic grasp of setting up the authentication using JWT Bearer tokens and I'm even solid enough to generate the tokens.
What has me confused is the actual login process, especially regarding data flow between client and server and how the tokens/cookies are managed. I've gone through various resources including this Medium article, but it's still unclear.
Here are my assumptions and current understanding (for my purposes, my client app is a Razor Pages app built on .net8):

Client and Data Store Interaction: the client app doesn't interact directly with the data store so it doesn't use a DbContext or libraries like ASP.NET Identity within its service container.
Login Request Handling: The client sends a login request with the username and password to an API endpoint which verifies the credentials against stored user data or via an OpenID provider.
Token Management: On successful authentication, the API sends back a bearer token to be used for future API calls. For security reasons, it's recommended to store this token in a secure HttpOnly cookie.

My concerns are these:

If the token is stored in an HttpOnly cookie, how exactly is it used in subsequent API requests. Javascript can't access it so what about my fetch requests to the API?
I know common practice is to build an Authorization header with the Bearer token but I can't even do this with an HttpOnly cookie...

So what's the real-world way to issue and use tokens in the Authorization header?
To illustrate my setup, here's code for a login endpoint:
app.MapPost("/login", async (LoginModel model, UserService userService, TokenService tokenService) =>
{
    var userExists = await userServiec.UserExistsAsync(model.Username);
    if (!userExists) return Results.Unauthorized();

    var user = await userService.SignInUserAsync(model);
    if (user == null) return Results.Unauthorized();

    var token = tokenService.GenerateToken(model);
    return Results.Ok(token);
});

So this is what I've got so far and it seems simple enough to work with the token from here...
const token = getTokenFromLocalStorage()

fetch(`api_endpoint`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }
    body: ...
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => { ... })

Storing it in localStorage or sessionStorage or anywhere on the user's browser, for that matter, seems like a terrible idea.
So, assuming I've got my Authentication middleware right, what are the parts that I'm missing?

"Javascript can't access it " - it should be sent by browser automatically with the request, no need to access it via js.

"To illustrate my setup, here's code for a login endpoint" - your code does not set a cookie it just returns the token in the response.

I was unaware of the cookie at the time I wrote the endpoint so my understanding was that it simply needed to return the token but then I discovered this is ferociously insecure so now I'm unsure how to proceed.

Inject HttpContext into your login handler and use HttpContext.Response to set the http-only cookie.

So cookie... Authorization header... Am I conflating two different authentication methodologies here or otherwise attempting to use some unholy combination of the two?

Okay well I guess expecting to have my questions answered on this platform was a bit naïve of me... Probably should've known better... Maybe I'll career change to do something people actually understand...

I would like to help you but do not have enough experience with frontend to give the definitive answer and do not have enough time to investigate at the moment. Personally I would use cookie-based auth for working with frontend app. It should be pretty straightforward.

I think I'm missing a step here... Presumably, we can push the token into an HttpOnly Cookie for requests following the login which I'm doing, but the missing step, I think, is then doing a sign in on the auth provider in the frontend app and populate info there from what the API returned... potentially... I'm rubber duck debugging here.
